# Special entries like "C>4" or "R<2" in this chart

Tags: texas-hold-em, strategy, pre-flop

I came across this [chart](https://www.cardschat.com/pkimg/strat/poker-odds-chart.pdf). I guess it is for limit Texas Hold'em, preflop betting strategy. R=Raise, C=Call etc.
I don't understand the yellow entries like "C>4" and "R<2". What do they mean?

Addition:
Why do I think this is limit Texas Hold'em? Because it is talking about caps, see bottom line: "CAP = Against a cap". In limit games, after 1 bet and 3 raises, no further raise is allowed typically. I read the four columns in the chart as "NR = against a bet", "R = against a bet and a raise", "RR = against a bet and 2 raises", "CAP = against a bet and 3 raises".

Comment: At the bottom it says 6 Players Max, so it's probably no-limit.

Comment: @HerbWolfe I've added an explanation why I think it is for limit

Answer (score 2):

I think that the conditional refers to the number of players in the hand.

"C > 4" means call, if there are more than 4 players who are in the hand/have acted in front of you.

"R < 2" means raise, if less than 2 players in front of you have acted.

It's unclear how that applies, for example, when the hero is UTG with a small pocket pair. The chart advises to call with more than 4 players in the hand, but counting the blinds, there are only 2 other players, which seems to indicate hero should fold, so why not just leave it blank?

Comment: Number of active players in some way might make sense. But I'm not totally convinced, because of scenarios as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me like it is a conditional.

I think "C>4" would mean call if you are facing a raise from position 4 or later.

"R>4" Would be the same thing, except you would reraise if you are facing a raise from position 4 or later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that it looks like a conditional. But I don't think it is about pot odds. For example the line TT: Pocket pairs always have a preflop chance of 1:7,5 of hitting a set on the flop. There is no need to further include a conditional in that line.

Comment: @azimut i think i figured it out, it is based on position. I edited my answer.

Comment: nah, I don't agree. Look at "R<1" at UTG, 88, column "NR" = "no raise". That would mean that with 88 in UTG position, you would raise if the last raise (there is none!) came from position < 1 (position 1 is the small blind who had no chance to act so far!). That doesn't make sense.